# Why does this promise code never run?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, ecmascript-2016, node.js-tape

As you can see in the .gif below, I call tape.js twice in my integration tests and it works fine. But the second time I run the tests, after I've commented out the code to insert test data into my database, the body of the tape.js function never runs.

Why does this happen?

[image]

I've put a breakpoint in my database code and it finishes and calls `resolve()` before the next tape.js test runs so I don't get it.

Here's my test class, followed by database class:

```
import tape = require('tape');
const testData = require('../../../helper/data');
import * as db from '../../../helper/integration/database';

helper.setTestEnvironmentVariableOn();
const startedServer : hapi.Server = require('../../../../src/app');

(async function runTests() {
  recreateDatabase();
  await db.runQuery(getInsertGetRolesTestPermissionsSql());
  await test_getRoles_returnsAllRoles();

  recreateDatabase();
  await db.runQuery(getInsertGetUsersRolesTestPermissionsSql());
  await test_getUsersRoles_userCanGetHerOwnRoles();
  await startedServer.stop();
})();

function test_getRoles_returnsAllRoles() {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    tape(testeeName + 'GET /roles returns all, and only, Ekaya roles', async (assert) => {
      await helper.createNewUser();
      superagent
      .get(testData.url + `roles`)
      .set('token', testData.token)
      .end( (error: any , result: superagent.Response) => {
        assert.equals(error, null);           
        assert.end();
        resolve();
      });
    });
  });
}

function test_getUsersRoles_userCanGetHerOwnRoles() {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    tape(testeeName + 'GET /users/id/roles gives a user her own roles', async (assert) => {
      const userid = '635de6dc-0df9-43f4-96dc-922bca541515';
      const token = await helper.getTokenForUser(userid);
        superagent
        .get(testData.url + `users/`+userid+`/roles`)
      .set('token', token)
        .end( (error: any , result: superagent.Response) => {
        assert.equals(error, null);                 
            assert.end();
        resolve();
        });
    });
  });
}

function getInsertGetUsersRolesTestPermissionsSql() : string {
  return `
    INSERT INTO enum.permissions(permissions_id, name,...
  `;
}

function getInsertGetRolesTestPermissionsSql() {
  return `
    delete fr...`;
}
```

Database class:

```
import * as pg from "pg";
import 'reflect-metadata';
const Config = require('../../../src/config');
const config = new Config();

export function runQuery(sql: string) : Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<any>(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const _db = new pg.Client(config.ekaya_local_connection_string);
        await connect(_db);
        _db.query(sql, function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                console.error('Error running query', error);
          _db.end();
          reject(error);
                return;
            }
        _db.end();
            resolve(result);
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
    });
}

function connect(_db: pg.Client) : Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>(  function(resolve, reject) {
    try {
        _db.connect(function(error) {
            if (error) {
                console.error('Could not connect to postgres in integration test helper', error);
                reject(error);
          return;
            }
            resolve(null);
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE - after vitaly-t's suggestion**

New database code, no effect on the problem:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
const Config = require('../../../src/config');
const config = new Config();
const pgp = require("pg-promise")();

export function runQuery(sql: string) : any {
return new Promise<any>(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {          
      const _db = pgp(config.ekaya_local_connection_string);
      const result = await _db.query(sql);
      pgp.end();
      resolve({rows: result}); 
    }
    catch (error) {reject(error);}
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't think `Promise<any>(async (resolve, reject) => {})` is correct. This should read `Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {})`.

Comment: `async` is required before functions to tell the compiler you use `await` inside the function. If I remove it I can't use `await` anymore.

Comment: That connection looks bad indeed. If you want `pg` with promises, why not just use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise)? Then you wouldn't need to reinvent the basics. Something always ends up wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of that library. I will try it tomorrow morning and reply.

Comment: Sadly that didn't make a difference. The execution still disappears on the same line in my tape test and never returns nor errors.

Comment: @Richard I have corrected the pg-promise code you provided ;)

Comment: Your version doesn't close the connection immediately. I need that.  And it doesn't return `{rows:}` (so all my existing tests still work based on the old pg). Also, it still won't fix my problem :(  I think the error is probably in my main await code in the .gif somehow, not a database thing.